# how to import the wallet generated from geth into parity through the passphase?

Tags: wallets, parity, parity-wallet, import

I have create a eth wallet by using geth, which is a go-lang based ethereum command line interface.

```
~ geth account new
 WARN [08-13|16:57:51] No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
 Your new account is locked with a password. Please give a password. Do not forget this password.
 Passphrase:
 Repeat passphrase:
 Address: {6d28522f27971cf42efa6d100576b1b34fc63188}
```

Now i have the address and the passphrase, and I am trying to import this wallet into parity, however in the account UI, I can't find any option to import the wallet

[image]

any ideas?

---

By using the **geth accout list** command, I can find my account keystore file.
But still in working with Parity to load the wallet with geth keystore option, the UI is just like the image below, i can't forward to load the keystore json file, i just installed parity two days ago.

The keystone json file is at the path in my ubuntu system

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to find keystore file on your computer. It is located in folder keystore. Name of the particular file will be something like `UTC--2017-12-19T09-12-08`. *Use `search: keystore` to find this folder*. 
2) Select Geth keystore in your Parity and upload the file you've found.

Comment: Thanks, @Roman, I found the keystore file but Parity doesn't seem to allow me to upload the file. In addition, by using the geth account create should also input the passphrase, would i need to use the passphrase

Comment: @user824624 [screenshot](https://image.ibb.co/bP24QR/2017_12_19_15_57_14.png) this is how it looks in my case. Parity see all of keystores, even those which are from testnet. In which folder your keystore is stored? Does it look something like `C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore`?

Comment: I am using ubuntu, i have uploaded a screenshot of the path

Comment: Try `copy it into your $HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys directory. Parity will import all keys found there.` According to [FAQ](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/FAQ:-Backup,-Restore,-and-Files).

Answer (score -1):

It was pretty easy to merely to do as Roman suggested: copy the keys from the ethereum keystore directory (e.g. $HOME/.ethereum/keystore) to the parity key folder: $HOME/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys

A quick confirmation that it took is accomplished by:
parity account list

[your geth accounts should now be listed by parity]

Hope this all works out for you. DW

Comment: That answer has already been given.